# django Manager on 2. class-level?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I want to write the Manager of a Model into the Model-class itself.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pub_date'] # Newest first

    class Manager(models.Manager):

        def by_slug(self, slug):
            slug = slug.strip().lower()
            return self.get(slug=slug)

    objects = Manager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or generate_slug(self.title)
        self.pub_date = self.pub_date or timezone.now()
        self.mod_date = timezone.now()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\niklas\Desktop\blog_project\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\niklas\Desktop\blog_project\blog\models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Post(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 99, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 219, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    unbound method contribute_to_class() must be called with Manager instance as first argument (got ModelBase instance instead)
```

Can you tell me why this error occurs and if what I want to do is even possible?

Comment: Interesting. I kind of like this structure, with the Manager on the Model. I'm not sure of the exact funkiness that's going on here, but the quick fix is obviously to just put the Manager outside the Model. I didn't know that an enclosing class would be passed through to the enclosed class's `__new__`, but that appears to the case.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because I prefer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't, this is a bug in Django, you can report it :)

Comment: Thank you! The ticket is here [@code.djangoproject.com](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19040).